# The relationship between eigenvalues of a covariance matrix and the variances of the same data matrix after using eigenvectors as bases

Tags: pca, covariance-matrix, matrix, eigenvalues, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have a data matrix $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ with $M$ features, $N$ samples and zero means ($M \lt N$). The covariance matrix of $\mathbf{X}$ is $\mathbf{C_x}=\frac{1}{N}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^T$, where $T$ is the transpose. We can find the eigendecomposition of $\mathbf{C_x}=\mathbf{U}\Sigma\mathbf{U}^T$ and we can construct $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{X}$ to achieve the diagonal covariance matrix of $\mathbf{Y}$, which is $\mathbf{C_Y}=\Sigma$.

When I look into the equation $\mathbf{C_Y}=\frac{1}{N}\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^T$ (All columns of $\mathbf{U}$ is used, so I am just using eigenvectors as basis without feature reduction.), it seems all the diagnoal entries will be larger than zero ($\ge 0 $), which are variances of all the features. But when I check the equation $\mathbf{C_Y}=\Sigma$, the $\Sigma$ of symmetric $\mathbf{C_X}$ doesn't seem to guarantee all eigenvalues $\ge 0$, as symmetric only gives me real eigenvalues and there might be some negative eigenvalues. So, I think there must be something wrong but I didn't notice that. Really need some help here.

Comment: Because $C_Y$ is manifestly positive-semidefinite, no eigenvalue can be negative.

Comment: @whuber Really thanks for the comment! But I didn't really see how $\mathbf{C_Y}$ is PSD, could you please enlighten me a little more?

Comment: For any vector $x,$ $x^\prime C_Y x = (x^\prime Y)(x^\prime Y)^\prime /N$ is a positive multiple of a sum of squares, whence it is nonnegative, proving $C_Y$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: @whuber Yes, you are right, now I see $\mathbf{C_Y}$ is PSD. Then, I think it also gives me $\mathbf{C_X}$ is PSD and $\Sigma$  only has eigenvalues that larger than or equals  0?